# Mule ESB z/OS integration

Tags: mule, mainframe, zos, cics

Needed some information on mainframe integration from Mule ESB Enterprise v 3.4 with z/OS. We don't have CICS Transaction Gateway setup and are using CICS Transaction Server v 3.2. Please let me know if there is an out-of-the-box way to achieve this integration (connection + data access {read+write}) to z/OS.
TIA.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, CICS is essentially an Application Server that typically sends and receives 3270 Terminal screens (it can be used to send/receive Web pages as well). Without Cics CTG you will probably have to screen scrape to get the data. The screen scraping could be done on the mainframe.

Comment: Currently we send/receive data to z/os using webmethods 'CICS sockets'. These are real-time requests(+responses) (sync blocking calls) and are not data sync/replication happening between wm and z/os. I am exploring if we can achieve the same from Mule @ a bare minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have details for a mainframe specific implementation, but I've been working with Mule for a while now and might be able to help you get to a solution.

Mule is a standalone server that runs on a machine that has Java installed on it. If z/OS has Java installed, you may be able to unpack the Mule package and start it right away. Just make sure JAVA_HOME and PATH are set properly. MULE_HOME gets set during the startup

Comment: But even if Mule is locally deployed on z/OS, how will it interact with the mainframe ? If we were to consider the CICS region, I am assuming this is currently only through CICS Transaction Gateway (we don't have CTG installed on z/OS LPARs).

Answer (score 0):

We have good success with Mule and CICS. In our case, we use MQ to get transactions into CICS, but pretty much any method is possible - even batch, if volume is low. We've created Mule connectors for some key apps, and this makes it drop-dead simple to create complex Mule flows that drive CICS (or other mainframe services).